# Local JS file wont link (Maybe because of bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I linked a personal JavaScript file to my website and as it stands the JavaScript won't actually execute on my index page.

I have a slight feeling it is because of how I linked my bootstrap and js after but just cant seem to get it.

HTML & JS file are below. Thanks in advance for any help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Bootstrap test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bangers' rel='stylesheet'>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </head>




    <body>          
        <!--Navigation bar-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark navbar-fixed-top transparent sticky-top" id="navbar">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                <img src="images/DallE_Extendo-removebg.png" width="80" height="60" alt="">
                </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="aboutus.html">About us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="products.html">Products</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="contactus.html">Contact us</a>
                    </li>                        
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!--NavBar Ends-->


        <!--Content Begins-->
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-left:0; padding-right:0;">
              <img src="images/Charlie-Co.-Barbershop-West-Chester-3.png" class="img" width="100">
              <a href="#" class="carousel-caption">Book now through booksy!</a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9 border-right border-bottom border-dark" style="padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0;">
              <h1 style="text-align: center; text-decoration: underline;">#</h1>
              <h1>Opening hours</h1>
              <p>Hours could change depending on Holidays & Bank Holidays</p>
              <table>
                <tr class="monday fvl-d">
                    <td><span>Monday</span></td>
                    <td>8.00 - 11.30</td>
                    <td>14.30 - 18.00</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="tuesday fvl-d">
                    <td><span>Tuesday</span></td>
                    <td>8.00 - 11.30</td>
                    <td>14.30 - 18.00</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="wednesday fvl-d">
                    <td><span>Wednesday</span></td>
                    <td>8.00 - 12.00</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="thursday fvl-d">
                    <td><span>Thursday</span></td>
                    <td>8.00 - 11.30</td>
                    <td>14.30 - 18.00</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="friday fvl-d">
                    <td><span>Friday</span></td>
                    <td>12.00 - 22.00</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="saturday fvl-d">
                    <td><span>Saturday</span></td>
                    <td>17.00 - 22.00</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="sunday fvl-d">
                    <td><span>Sunday</span></td>
                    <td>closed</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 border-left border-bottom border-dark" style="padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0;">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis non ultricies velit, eget suscipit velit. Nam laoreet magna ornare ex ornare ultrices. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aenean vel tincidunt velit. Nam sed est metus. Maecenas commodo dolor non lorem semper malesuada. Aliquam tempor blandit sapien in sodales. Integer eu metus efficitur ligula mattis pretium. Donec finibus mi non sodales condimentum. Donec elementum nunc quis mauris pulvinar porta. Sed sed est eget justo vestibulum malesuada vitae at nulla. Suspendisse quis efficitur lorem. Phasellus non ornare ante. Mauris ullamcorper, ligula in malesuada malesuada, purus nibh pretium dui, ac eleifend purus mauris vel nisi. Sed lacinia hendrerit magna at pharetra. Suspendisse quis varius diam, et ultricies dui. In scelerisque felis ac sapien bibendum, eget iaculis nisl egestas. Proin tempor et magna eu molestie. Praesent consequat lorem ut accumsan vehicula. Nunc luctus turpis non sollicitudin fermentum. Fusce nec viverra ex, sit amet tristique turpis.</p>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12" id="footer">
                <div class="col-md-3" style="font-size: 10px;">
                    <p>#</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3" style="padding-left: 10%; text-align: center;">
                    <p>#<br> #</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3" style="padding-left: 10%; padding-bottom: 1%;">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/rsz_1rsz_insta.png"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/rsz_twitter.png"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/rsz_1facebook-removebg-preview.png"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3" style="padding-left: 10%; text-align: center;">
                    <p>#<br> #</p>
                </div>
            </div>  
          </div>
        </div>


        <!--Content Ends-->
    </body>
</html>
```

JS code

```
    const time = () => {

    const activerow = document.querySelector('#activerow');

    const monday = document.querySelector('.monday');
    const tuesday = document.querySelector('.tuesday');
    const wednesday = document.querySelector('.wednesday');
    const thursday = document.querySelector('.thursday');
    const friday = document.querySelector('.friday');
    const saturday = document.querySelector('.saturday');
    const sunday = document.querySelector('.sunday');


    switch (new Date().getDay()) {

        case 1:
            monday.setAttribute("id", "activerow");
            break;
        case 2:
            tuesday.setAttribute("id", "activerow");
            break;
        case 3:
            wednesday.setAttribute("id", "activerow");
            break;
        case 4:
            thursday.setAttribute("id", "activerow");
            break;
        case 5:
            friday.setAttribute("id", "activerow");
            break;
        case 6:
            saturday.setAttribute("id", "activerow");
            break;
        case 0:
            sunday.setAttribute("id", "activerow");
            break;
    }

}
time();
```

Any fixes that you guys might have would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you referring to this?: `<script src="index.js"></script>`  In your browser's debugging tools, on the network tab, is the request for `index.js` made?  What is the server's response?  Are there any errors on the browser's development console?  If you use the browser's script debugger to step through the code, what happens?

Comment: Hi David,

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'setAttribute')
    at time (index.js:26:22)
    at index.js:40:1

Thats the error above from the dev console. Looks like its calling to null but dont understand why is the issue :/

Comment: Think [about deferring the script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) or moving its call to just before the `</body>` tag.